# Book set after a nuclear war, with people living underground

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

It's set after a nuclear war with China and America is living underground and they have sections to see how people survive in different conditions like food and water and amount of people in them.

Comment: It might help to give more details about the story, just in case there is more than one book about survivors of a nuclear war living underground.

Comment: Sounds like the 'great war of 2077' and the 'vault experiment' background to the video game "Fallout".

Comment: they live in caves and the book changes pov from different characters in different areas

Comment: Sounds a bit like Hugh Howey's _Silo_ saga? It sounds most like the second novel/omnibus in the series, _Shift_, but the first one is called _Wool_.

Answer (score 1):

Level Seven by Mordechai Roshwald, perhaps?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You can make this a better answer by adding details of the plot and setting to show how it matches the question.  You might want to read [answer].